# google authenticator vs vbscript

Tags: authentication, vbscript

I have implemented this http://jacob.jkrall.net/totp/ in vbscript.

My code given the same hex gives the right 6-digit otp, so that part is working.

I've also verified the HMAC-SHA-1. encoding against an online generator, http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output, same input gives same output.

My time is the same as http://www.currenttimestamp.com/

I've generated a qrcode at http://www.qr-koder.dk/ with the string otpauth://totp/$LABEL?secret=$SECRET and the google authenticator app reads the code and starts outputting the 6 digit code changing every 30 seconds.

BUT THE CODES FROM THE APP DOES NOT MATCH THE 6-DIGIT CODE THE VBSCRIPT GENERATES!

I've even tried trunc(time/30) +/-7500 steps to see if it was a timezone/daylight saving problem, to no avail.

As the other parts of the routine to generate the 6 digits seem to work I've come to the conclusion I don't understand this:

the url on the qr-code is

```
otpauth://totp/$LABEL?secret=$SECRET
```

with the explanation

> LABEL can be used to describe the key in your app, while SECRET is the
>   16-character base32-encoded shared secret, which is now known to both
>   the client and the server.

So when I calculate HMAC-SHA-1(SECRET, time()/30)

should the SECRET be the same string given to both the app and the calculation?

If I select a secret of `1234567890`, the base32 is `GEZDGNBVGY3TQOJQ` according to http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base32_encode.html.

Should I then take

```
HMAC-SHA-1("1234567890", time()/30)
```

or

```
HMAC-SHA-1("GEZDGNBVGY3TQOJQ", time()/30)
```

?

I believe I've tried both, and neither works.

Answer (score 1):

The system unix time is correct.

I guess the problem might be with the secret in your HMAC-SHA-1 function. It very much depends on what the HMAC-SHA-1 expects.

Your string "123456790" might be a binary string. Is it an ascii representation or utf8? I.e. is this string 10 bytes or 20 bytes long?

I recommend getting the input string in your VBScript right.

On the other hand, instead of writing your own VBScript, you can also use a ready made solution like the [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org) authentication server, which is open source and also comes with TOTP.